# How to get the Duration with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, duration

Need help how to calculate the duration using PostgreSQL. In my example below, let's say that the location of a person is recorded at a specific time.

```
timestamp        location   
02JAN19:00:00:00 home
02JAN19:05:00:00 work1
02JAN19:06:00:00 work2
02JAN19:07:00:00 home
```

I'd only like to retain the first time this person was not in home location, and the duration this person was outside home location. This person was outside home from 05:00 to 06:59 AM, this duration which we'd like to calculate.

Thus, Resulting dataset as follows:

```
timestamp location duration (in Minutes)
02JAN19:06:00:00 work2    119
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the difference of maximum time at home and minimum of time  not at home, you may use

```
max(case when location  = 'home' then  timestamp end ) 
     - min(case when location != 'home' then timestamp end )




SELECT extract(epoch FROM max(
     CASE
          WHEN location = 'home' THEN TIMESTAMP
     END
) - min(
     CASE
          WHEN location != 'home' THEN TIMESTAMP
     END
) )::int / 60 - 1 AS duration
 from
t;
```

If you want the rest of the columns before the max duration,

```
with dur as
(
SELECT extract(epoch FROM max(
     CASE
          WHEN location = 'home' THEN TIMESTAMP
     END
) - min(
     CASE
          WHEN location != 'home' THEN TIMESTAMP
     END
) )::int / 60 - 1 AS duration
 from
t ) 
select t.*,dur.duration from t cross join dur 
  order by CASE
          WHEN location != 'home' THEN TIMESTAMP
     END desc nulls last limit 1
```

If you want it for each person, you use `GROUP BY person` or whatever id that represents unique person and then use `DISTINCT ON` to filter out the 
greatest timestamp instead of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=741d41fb05b333ef0d5c2670a759aa2c)